# proving n linearly independent vectors are generating

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given n linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2, ... , v_n$ in a real vector space $V$ where $\mbox{dim}(V)=n$, how do I prove the vectors generate $V$?

I understand why this is true, I can visualize it in $2D$ vectors but for the life of me I just can't figure out how to generalize it or put it in proper mathematical language.

So far all I've got are the definitions of linear independence and generation. I know I can use the rules of vector space operations to show that the linear combination is in $V$ but can I use it to show it is the span?

Comment: If $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in V$ are linearly independent then $span(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a $n$-dimensional subspace of $V$. How many $n$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ are there?

Answer (score 2):

Dimension of $V$ is the minimum amount of vectors are required to span it. And by definition, if $n = dimV$, then the smallest basis is $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$..... and you have $n$ linearly independent vectors.

There are multiple proofs out there to show that this spans it. Try writing your vectors as column vectors in a matrix $A$ and show that it spans any vector in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's easier and more "constructive" to go from the other definition of the dimension as the largest possible number of linearly independent vectors. Let's prove that any vector $v$ is a linear combination of $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$.

Well, the set $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n,v\}$ is linearly dependent by definition as it contains $n+1$ vectors. So there exists a nontrivial linear combination that produces the zero vector: $$\alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n + \alpha_{n+1}v=\mathbf{0}.$$
The coefficient $\alpha_{n+1}$ is necessarily nonzero (explain why). Thus $$v = -\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_{n+1}} v_1 - \cdots  -\frac{\alpha_n}{\alpha_{n+1}} v_n,$$ and so we therefore see that any vector is a linear combination of the given $n$ vectors.